# Recording multitrack in FL studio with multiple USB-connected microphones

Tags: homerecording, fl-studio

I have two mics which I connect to my PC via XLR to USB cables, but when I record in FL studio it only record the default mic. I have read that for multi track recording an Audio interface is needed, is this true?

Answer (score 0):

Yes .An Audio interface is preferred due to possible compression limitation on your PC Sound card . 
Roland created many such as CD-2U-Digital-Recording-Interface.Capturing audio is a sepreate matter to recording Midi

Comment: FL studios being a software can not overcome compression limitations which may exist in a PC sound card .In suggest contacting the PC maker or the maker of the sound card.

Answer (score 0):

A driver such as [ASIO4ALL](https://www.asio4all.org/) will let you connect several audio devices to be used at the same time.  Depending on what drivers your USB microphones use, this may work.  (I used to use this software to connect my Realtek sound card and Virtual Audio Cable into FL studio at the same time.)

There is a menu that looks like this

[image]

[Image Source](https://www.stantondj.com/media-downloads/deckadance-2/web_help/html/deckadance_audiosettings_asio4all.htm)

which is accessible from inside FL studio, once ASIO4ALL is installed.  You can select all devices which you want to use.  If two USB microphones show up here, then great!  You can use both of them.

This is not really recommended, since you will likely run into sync issues when the two microphones are separate audio devices.  You will not be able to make proper true stereo recordings, but you may be able to record two different sources (e.g. a singer and a guitarist) at the same time, as long as there is not much bleed between the two mics.